# How to pass information to a thread once it has been created

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

If you look at the code I have two ArrayLists that are called, pressed and released that are global. What I have to do is update those arrays with the keys that are to be pressed, then pass these updated arrays to my Thread, or update the thread.. this is the part where I'm a little lost on what I have to do.

The currently example(untested if runs), is a basic example of what I had in my actual program. When I ran it it would press the buttons once, then it would throw and error, I can't remember the error as I can't test it right now, but it had to do with the way I was using the thread.

***QUESTION***
How do I pass the arrays to my Thread, once the thread has been started.

***Code Example:***

```
import oscP5.OscEventListener;
import oscP5.OscMessage;
import oscP5.OscP5;
import oscP5.OscStatus;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Main implements OscEventListener {

protected BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1024);

Producer producer = new Producer(this._KeyQue);
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(this._KeyQue);
ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest(this._KeyQue);

Thread prod;
Thread con;
Thread threadT;

OscP5 osc = new OscP5(this, 22556);

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.setup();
}

public void setup() {
    prod = new Thread(producer);
    con = new Thread(consumer);
    threadT = new Thread(threadTest);

    prod.start();
    con.start();
    threadT.start();

}

@Override
public void oscEvent(OscMessage theMessage) {
    float val = Float.parseFloat(theMessage.arguments()[0].toString());

    if (val == 1.0) {
        producer.addKey(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        producer.addKey(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    } else {
        consumer.removeKey(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    }
   threadTest.run();
}

@Override
public void oscStatus(OscStatus theStatus) {}

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue = null;

    public void addKey(int key) {
        try {
            this._KeyQue.put(key);
            System.out.println("Key " + key +" added to queue");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue) {
        this._KeyQue = _KeyQue;
    }

    public void run() {

    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue = null;

    public void removeKey(int key) {
        try {
            this._KeyQue.remove(key);
            System.out.println("key " + key + " removed from queue");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue) {
        this._KeyQue = _KeyQue;
    }

    public void run() {

    }
}

public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    protected BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue = null;

    public ThreadTest(BlockingQueue<Integer> _KeyQue) {
        this._KeyQue = _KeyQue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            while(!this._KeyQue.isEmpty()) {
                for (Integer x : this._KeyQue) {
                    System.out.println("Keys in que: " + x);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

***Edit:***
  Ok, so I've taken a look at threads and BlockingQueue's, but the thing I still can't figure out is how to continue to run the ***ThreadTest's run()*** method without locking the program. In this example it doesn't run at all. When I directly call ***threadTest.run()*** it locks the program within it and doesn't allow for adding or removing elements.

So what I need to do is be able to run a thread in the background that is constantly running, looping through ***_KeysQueue()*** and, in this example, printout the number associated with the keys. This should all happen while allowing me to add and remove keys.

Comment: If you are unsure what I'm trying to do, please ask some probing questions. It's hard to articulate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you need to determine what the error was...

Comment: Also, it's unclear what your actual question is here.

Comment: I know that I'm not using the thread correctly.. So I can only assume that If I learn how to use the thread and being able to update info with it, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: If you can't test, how would you know if problem is solved?

Comment: Once I'm home I'll be able to test, right now I'm at work, but I'm still doing research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `BlockingQueue` and a method to add elements that would be called from every other thread. You can have a static method `addKey` that could be accessed from every other thread and that would look for adding the new key to the `BlockingQueue`.

You can use there [the producer-consumer pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer) and you can see the book [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) or the link that led me to the book, in the blog [The Java Specialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue125.html). The book has examples of all queues, concurrent or synchronized lists, ways to implement code to do several things, and all without having to stop to read 50 pages about something. An example and a few paragraphs of every issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a setter method in your class

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
    ....
    public void setPressedList(ArrayList<Integer> e) {
       this.pressed = e;
    }
    public void setReleasedList(ArrayList<Integer> f)
    {
       this.released = f
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that might help, but I still have the problem of this is a thread that has been instantiated. There isn't a variable that I have to work off of. As you can at the top it says; Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadTest(bla,bla)).  So how do I access those methods?

Comment: just use t.setPressedList(list) ;

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayList** are not **thread-safe** so you should not used them this way : it could work or it could fail.

Moreover you should use some kind of **synchronization** mechanism instead of **busy-waiting** which consume resources for nothing.

So have a look at the **BlockingQueue** collection which will give you a simple data-passing mechanism between your threads.